# Why is my audio stream in WKWebView on iOS 9 not playing?

Tags: ios, ios9, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView with content that has an `<audio>` element pointing to a standard audio stream running on a Shoutcast server that will not play.  There are no errors or information in the JavaScript console and no errors in the debugger in Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to be [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/).  This new security feature in iOS 9 was silently preventing the `<audio>` element from connecting to the insecure audio stream.  Allowing arbitrary loads by adding this to my `info.plist` solved the problem:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: As an aside, whitelists can be created: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/

Answer (score 4):

I added this to the App Transport Security Settings plist and it solved the problem for me:

```
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key>
    <true/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If problem persist for some `<audio>`, replace "**touchstart click**" event by  "**touchend click**" in js

Check this [link](http://www.holovaty.com/writing/ios9-web-audio/) for more details